# Creating unique vectors for large dataset

Tags: r, loops, vector

I am trying to find the Atkinson Index measure for individual countries that spans over 11,000 observations. I have the decile measures for each specific observation which I can create an individual vector ex. c(d1, d2,...d10) for each single observation and compute the Atkinson Index but I am sure there is a quicker way to do this across 11,000 observations. Is there any possible way I can direct R to create a unique vectors across all 11,000 observations that use the deciles that are specific to each individual observation?

I am still rather new to coding in R, but I have tried to see if I can create some kind of loop that would return a vector pertaining to the deciles that corresponding with each individual observation.

```
id2 <- c(3.86, 5.29, 6.38, 7.32, 8.38, 9.35, 10.82, 12.47, 14.90, 21.22)
atkinson(id2, epsilon = 1)
[1] 0.1079504
```

I can do this over 11,000 times but obviously that will take awhile, is there a way to construct R (a loop?) to do something along this lines for each individual observation?

Here is an explanation to the computation of the Atkinson index:

Suppose that y_1,…,y_10 are the decile shares of income owned (earned, shared) by successive 10% of the population. The average share (arithmetic mean) is A=(y_1+⋯+y_10)/10; The geometric mean is G=√(10&y_1∙…∙y_10 ); An approximation of the Atkinson inequality measure (ε=1) is equal to 100∙(1-G/A).

I am using the 'acid' package that has the atkinson function.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use the `matrixStats` package to do things in a vectorized fashion:

```
# LOAD PACKAGE
library(matrixStats)

# SOME MADE UP DATA
data <- matrix(runif(11000*10), ncol=10)

# CALCULATE ARITHMETIC MEAN
A <- rowMeans(data)

# CALCULATE GEOMETRIC
G <- rowProds(data)^(1/10)

#CALCULATE SCORES
atkinson <- 100 * (1 - G/A)
```